# Upload File in a folder without using submit button in Django

Tags: python, html, django, bootstrap-4, file-upload

I am on a Django project and the scenario is that I want to save file in a folder without clicking on submit button. I am already saving the file in a folder with the help of submit button but now the scenario has changed and now I want to save file without clicking on submit button.
Here are the details of my files:

views.py:

```
def compliance_check(request):`
 if request.method == 'POST':`
  uploaded_file = request.FILES['doc']`
  print(uploaded_file.name)`
  print(uploaded_file.size)`
  fs = FileSystemStorage()`
  fs.save(uploaded_file.name, uploaded_file)`
  messages.info(request, 'your file ' + uploaded_file.name + " has been uploaded successfully")
  return render(request, 'enroll/abc.html')
```

upload.html:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="file" id="file" name="doc">
<input type="submit" name = "doc" value="upload file" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" disabled /> 
</form>
```

settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join('/home/t/Desktop/folder name')
MEDIA_URL = '/upload/'
```

urls.py:

```
path('compliance_check/', views.compliance_check, name='compliance check'),
```

Now the situation is that I am already saving file in a folder. But, now, I want to save file without clicking on submit button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your html:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="myform">
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="file" id="file" name="doc" onchange="document.myform.submit()">
</form>
```

This will submit the form, if the user closes the file selection dialog (I assume, this is what you want). Chose a better name for your form than "myform".

Comment: please try to understand the question, I want to remove the html button <input type="submit" name = "doc" value="upload file" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" disabled /> which is this line and without this I want to upload file. so, now update your answer

Comment: Yes, you can remove the button after including the changes I suggest. Did you try them? Or maybe you need to clarify your question, what should trigger then the upload of your file.

Comment: I have tried your code and It's working successfully, now if I want to cancel the uploaded file in this case, so what can be the scenario??